# Adobe AEM form with custom javascript events throwing guideLib, guide.js, guideBridge, or guideRuntime undefined or ... is not a function

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, aem

This is going to be a problem that very few if any people have, but it was time consuming and difficult to solve and i figured it out, so here is the solution, one other person in the world who has this problem.

Are you getting all kinds of weird "this.getOnOffValueFromModelValue is not a function" kinds of errors from  guideRuntime.js, guide.js , or guidelib -- or other adobe frontend libraries that you do not control?

These may not apply to you directly but if they do definitely keep reading:

1. Are you using webpack and including custom code on the page elsewhere (perhaps via a data-sly-use or something)?
2. Does your project use lodash? or perhaps another library that uses a "_" global variable?
3. Or perhaps jQuery? or other frontend library?

Then you may be asking questions like:

- Why is my form not working properly?
- Why is some stuff on the form just not working?
- Some rules are just not working... why not and how do i fix them?

Oh I'll feed you, baby birds.

( can someone with a higher reputation add the tags adobe-form, aem-form to this, please)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

If you're using Webpack, add this to your module rules:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { parser: { amd: false } }
 // ... your other rules
  ]
}
```

or if you're not using webpack, make sure your own variables are not leaking into the global scope, because adobe's are and yours may overwrite theirs or vice-versa.

---

The explanation that may be applicable even if you're not using webpack that may get you in the right direction:

Adobe's client libraries (like guide.js and guideRuntime and the like) aren't particularly good at dependency injecting their stuff. Their code leaks global variables a lot. For example (see picture below) they use underscore's _.each a lot. if you're using lodash, the function signatures are different-- underscores' allows you to define a "this" context as the third parameter, whereas lodash's doesn't.

So, in our case, our lodash was overwriting their underscore causing a bunch of weird issues... EVEN THOUGH we were NOT declaring lodash globally anywhere. [WEBPACK WAS defining lodash globally](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4465#issuecomment-285850829)

So moral of the story, open up console, check to see if any of your libraries are defined globally, and if they are, figure out how to make them not global until Adobe decides to fix their stuff (don't hold your breath).

[image: adobe guideruntime not injecting underscore properly]